# JSONB query how to check at-least-one array containment

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10

How do I get the query below to return 'true'  to reflect that I need at least one of the value in the array on the right, to be contained in the array on the left?

```
SELECT   '["fun", "movies"]'::jsonb  @> '["fun", "movies","x"]'::jsonb;
```

The above returns `false` (because 'x' is not in the array on the left).

I have tried  the `?|` [operator link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html)

```
SELECT   '["fun", "movies"]'::jsonb  ?| '["fun", "movies","x"]'::jsonb;
```

but postgres returns an error

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ?| jsonb LINE 2: SELECT
> '["fun", "movies"]'::jsonb  ?| '["fun", "movies","x...
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add
> explicit type casts. SQL state: 42883 Character: 147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to "convert" jsonb array to postgres array first:

```
t=# SELECT   '["fun", "movies"]'::jsonb  ?| translate('["fun", "movies","x"]'::jsonb::text,'[]','{}')::text[];
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```